# To repair, or sell: that is the question

Tags: repair, volvo

1998 Volvo S70 4D 117k miles.  No accidents, inherited from 2nd owner.

I've got a big list of repairs to make:

- ABS control unit throws 8 fault codes, can replace w/ a rebuilt unit
- Front strut assembly and mounts blown, have to replace
- Front lower control arm and ball joint has too much play and won't pass SI
- Front sway bar links are worn out, got to replace
- Front outer CV boot leaking grease, replace
- Driver side door hinges pop, need professional spot welding
- Driver side door group switch busted, need to replace
- Needs an alignment, obviously

About $1300 in parts and 3rd party labor would be about $1k.

I'm looking for a minivan and want to unload this sedan. I've got an offer as-is for $900.  I think, if repaired, I could sell it PP for $2500, though KBB value is $2100. But doing the math, sounds like the as-is offer is best: $900 profit guaranteed vs. $600-$1000 profit if self-repaired vs. $200-$0 if shop-repaired.  Also, the line between self- and shop-repaired is blurry: I can only make some of these repairs myself.

Am I missing any detail that should change my mind?

Comment: Of course, the list of repairs isn't all or nothing: you could choose a few which are the most cost effective, perform those and skip the others.

Comment: [See my answer here](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/12183/85), as it may help you decide

Comment: @Movemorecommentslinktotop Yep, great answer thanks for the link.  I had three estimates on the work, and the CBA demonstrated it wasn't "worth" it.  Considering the negative equity incurred by repairs, and that the car didn't meet my needs even with positive equity, it really was just time to let it go.  Found a great 2012 Chrysler Town & Country.  If you want to post a similar answer here, I'll upvote and accept.

Comment: Could you place your comment as the answer?

Comment: This is a personal finance question, not a vehicle repair question.

Comment: @DavidWinslow I disagree. If it were strictly financial, there would be no question: the numbers were clear.  What wasn't clear is how valuable the car might be to others, which I could not quantify: for example, a Volvo enthusiast might pay a bit more than average for the mileage, despite the repairs needed.

Comment: A vehicle valuation is more off-topic than your CBA question.

Comment: @DavidWinslow I'm just not getting your argument.  Who else is better suited to answer valuation than ["vehicle maintenance experts"](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/192)?  Further, ["many automotive technicians and DIYers alike are passionate about cars and end up going through the buy/sell process a lot, and should have knowledge to share on the subject."](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/128).

Comment: I think this conversation should move to chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, traded it in for a 2012 Chrysler Town & Country Touring L.

I had three estimates on the work, and the cost-benefit analysis demonstrated keeping the Volvo wasn't "worth" it. Considering the negative equity incurred by repairs, and that the car didn't meet my needs even with positive equity, it really was just time to let it go.